# jQuery Validate custom validator with multiple params in metadata tag and message

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I want to use jQuery Validate to validate an age is between two years in a metadata tag, and specify the years as parameters.

The problem I have is I can't pass the parameters as an object so I don't know how to access them in the error message (and can't find any documentation on it).

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="dob" id="dob" validAge="[17,66]" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('validAge', function (value, element, params) {
        value = eLifeViewModel.age();
        if (value === '') {
            return false;
        }
        var range = JSON.parse(params);
        return value > range[0] && value < range[1];
    }, $.format('Applicants must be older than {0} and younger than {1} years of age'));
```

The output for {0} is my parameter string and {1} is the HTTPInputElement.

I've now written a minAge and maxAge function to get around this, but I'd still be keen to get a resolution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't find documentation, <s>because you can't do it.</s>

Using the jQuery Validation plugin and a custom method, you cannot declare the `validAge` rule inline when you need to pass parameters.

```
<input type="text" name="dob" id="dob" validAge="[17,66]" />
```

Only certain rules that can be declared with a boolean (can be declared as `class` names), or rules that are also HTML5 validation attributes can be declared inline.

For your custom method with parameters, it <s>must</s> (*can*) be declared within the `.validate()` method...

```
$('#myform').validate({
    // your options, rules, etc,
    rules: {
        dob: {
            validAge: [17,66]
        }
    }
});
```

---

**EDIT**:

As pointed out by @John Bubriski, this should be working.  The OP was not accessing the parameters correctly in his custom method.

The OP was using JSON.parse...

```
var range = JSON.parse(params);
```

which gives a syntax error in the console since it's not recognizing `params` as a valid JSON string.  Parsing the `params` variable is not necessary.

The parameters are passed into the function as `params`, so they can be accessed directly as `params[0]`, `params[1]`, etc.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('validAge', function (value, element, params) {
    value = eLifeViewModel.age();
    if (value === '') {  // <- You do NOT need this! 
    /* Use the "required" rule instead of this conditional */
        return false;
    }
    return value > params[0] && value < params[1];
}, $.format('Applicants must be older than {0} and younger than {1} years of age'));
```

Comment: Thought this was going to be the case. Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: It looks like this does in fact work in the latest version: http://jsfiddle.net/jbubriski/YQgEq/119/

Answer (score 7):

This does work, at least in the latest jQuery/Validate.  Here is a fiddle showing some custom validators, 3 of which take an array of parameters: http://jsfiddle.net/jbubriski/YQgEq/120/

Here is one of the examples that takes string params.  Instead of saying `data-rule-customname="true"`, you specify the parameters `data-rule-customname='["string",1,2,3]'`.

(*Note the flipping of quotes... using single quotes to denote the strings doesn't seem to work.  Use double quotes*)

Markup:

```
<div>
    Custom 3 (Requires 'pig' or 'mouse'): <input type="text" id="custom3" name="custom3" data-rule-required="true" data-rule-customv3='["pig","mouse"]' data-msg-customv3="Enter a cool animal name!" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("customv3", function(value, element, params) {
    if (this.optional(element))
        return true;

    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++)
        if (value == params[i])
            return true

    return false;
}, jQuery.validator.format("Please enter one of the following values: {0} {1}"));
```

The only issue with the above example is that I'm not sure if there is a way to dynamically generate the error message if you're expecting `n` parameters.  The current code works fine, but assumes 2 parameters.

I also have a blog post that details some other aspects of using attribute-based validation: http://johnnycode.com/2014/03/27/using-jquery-validate-plugin-html5-data-attribute-rules/

Comment: Nice! I was doing everything fine except for the flipped quotes. It helped me a lot since I'm using the html attributes to set the rules for specific fields.

Answer (score 2):

The `params` variable doesn't return a string but an object.

Try to pass the range directly from params :

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('validAge', function (value, element, params) {
        value = eLifeViewModel.age();
        if (value === '') {
            return false;
        }
        return value > params[0] && value < params[1];
    }, $.format('Applicants must be older than {0} and younger than {1} years of age'));
```

Comment: Thanks NMC, is there a way I can do that from the HTML metadata tag? Won't the value always be passed as a string?

Comment: It should eb already passed within the HTML tag. You just didnt use the params correctly. I beleive that the params[0] is you min and params[1] is your max age. You don;t have to parse the string.